# Pass a parameter from one PHP page to another - it always gets the biggest (MySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to pass product_id to the searchQuantityStaff page, but the biggest one is always retrieved no matter what. Any idea how to post the correct one? 
Apparently the loop populates the fields with the correct ID's but adding another product to the corresponding table with a bigger ID made the code pick this one's ID.

```html
<html>
   
<?php
include "db.php";

$by_name = $_POST["by_name"];
$by_product_id = $_POST["by_product_id"];
$by_price = $_POST["by_price"];
$by_description = $_POST["by_description"];
$by_ptype = $_POST["by_ptype"];
$by_release_date = $_POST["by_release_date"];
$by_mname = $_POST["by_mname"];
$by_manufacturer_id = $_POST["by_manufacturer_id"];
$by_manufacturer_city = $_POST["by_manufacturer_city"];



$query = "SELECT * FROM staff_search WHERE 
`Name` LIKE '%$by_name%' 
AND `Product ID` LIKE '%$by_product_id%' 
AND `Price` LIKE '%$by_price%' 
AND `Product Description` LIKE '%$by_description%' 
AND `Type` LIKE '%$by_ptype%' 
AND `Release Date` LIKE '%$by_release_date%' 
AND `Manufacturer Name` LIKE '%$by_mname%' 
AND `manufacturer ID` LIKE '%$by_manufacturer_id%' 
AND `manufactured in` LIKE '%$by_manufacturer_city%'  
";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$count = 0;
$count2 = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$count2 = $count2+1;
foreach ($row as &$value) {
 if($count == 0){
  $count = 1;
  echo $value; echo " ";
 }
 else{
  $count = 0;
 echo "<br>";
 }
}
 ?>  
 <form name="myForm<?php echo $count2; ?>" action="searchQuantityStaff.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="product_id" value = "<?php echo $row['Product ID']; ?>"  > <br/>
 <button type="submit">Look up quantity</button> 
 <?php
 
echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
}
?>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Sends the variable to:

```html
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  
 <div id="header">
 <h1><center>Thermionic Megastore</center></h1>
 <h2> Search </h2>
 </div>
 
 <p>
  <nav role="main">
  <br>
  Index
  </nav>
 </p>

<section id="main";>
<br>

<?php

include "db.php";
$product_id = $_POST["product_id"];


$query = "SELECT *  FROM quantity_result WHERE `Product ID` LIKE '%$product_id%'  ";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

foreach ($row as &$value) {
if($count == 0){
$count = 1;
#echo $value; echo " ";
}
else{
}
}

?>
Available: <?php  echo $row['Quantity'];  ?> </br>
In store:  <?php  echo $row['Retailer Name'];  ?></br>
Special price (if applicable): <?php  echo $row['Special Price'];  ?></br>
<?php
}

?>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND `manufacturer ID` LIKE '%$by_manufacturer_id%'
```

change this to

```
AND `manufacturer ID` LIKE '$by_manufacturer_id%'
```

I edited my answer according to your feedback. This will search for only starts with id.

For example assume to ids

123456 and 999123456

if you search 123 it will return 123456 because, we remove % sign.

Comment: Also all of your mysql structure is wrong. You should not use white space on your tables, columns etc. for example, not manufacturer ID, it should manufacturer_ID

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this made it so it cannot search by manufacturer_id. And the tip about not using spaces is good, I'll do that.

Comment: That seems to work, but this is still not resolving the problem with the product_id passing from the POST method, tried changing by_product_id as well and is getting the info for only 1 idem correctly, it's the one that has a different manufaccturer ID than the other 2 as those share the same.